# Latex - Problems with #

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've got a problem with this error:

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

This error appeared suddenly in strange place after I add next bibtex to my bibliography.

Error is in line 13 and there is no mater what is in this line (I removed current and error still remains. Here is part of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,draft]{mgr_eng}
%---packages---
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%---global definition---
\author{Marcin Kulisiewicz}
\title{Oznaczanie nastawienia słów z użyciem metod uczenia maszynowego}
\engtitle{Word's sentiment evaluation using machine learning methods}
\supervisor{prof. Aleksander Zgrzywa, D.Sc., Ph.D., Associate Professor, Department of Information Systems, Faculty of Computer Science and Management} 
\guardian{Tomasz Kajdanowicz, Ph.D., Department of Information Systems, Faculty of Computer Science and Management}
\field{Computer Science}
\specialisation{Information Systems}
```

And bibliography:

```
@inproceedings{Esuli2006sentiwordnet,
  added-at = {2009-01-29T21:09:18.000+0100},
  author = "Esuli, Andrea and Sebastiani, Fabrizio",
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/23e410e9b5d848e4e315b292253b6ed9d/hkorte},
  booktitle = {In Proceedings of the 5th Conference on Language Resources and Evaluation (LREC’06},
  interhash = {12da884807d2866aa148cde8b036d2c4},
  intrahash = {3e410e9b5d848e4e315b292253b6ed9d},
  keywords = {WordNet opinion_mining semantics},
  pages = {417--422},
  timestamp = {2009-01-29T21:09:18.000+0100},
  title = "SENTIWORDNET: A publicly available lexical resource for opinion mining",
  url = {SENTIWORDNET: A publicly available lexical resource for opinion mining},
  year = 2006
}

@inproceedings{pak2010twitter,
  added-at = {2013-10-24T16:04:56.000+0200},
  author = {Pak, Alexander and Paroubek, Patrick},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2b34319052fd2b3dae7647b5e87c64b21/folke},
  booktitle = {LREC},
  interhash = {ac930b0459a3c8a2fc2d74c52a475026},
  intrahash = {b34319052fd2b3dae7647b5e87c64b21},
  keywords = {NIP analysis mining opinion sentiment twitter},
  timestamp = {2013-10-24T16:04:56.000+0200},
  title = {Twitter as a Corpus for Sentiment Analysis and Opinion Mining.},
  url = {http://scholar.google.de/scholar.bib?=info:bSEeALDtz4oJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=de&ct=citation&cd=1},
  year = 2010
}

@inproceedings{jurafsky2014slajdy,
  author = {Jurafsky D., Manning C.},
  booktitle = {Coursera.com},
  keywords = {sentiment analysis natural language processing opinion mining},
  title = {Sentiment Analysis, [w:] Natural Language Processing.},
  year = 2014
}

@article{Feldman13cacm,
  added-at = {2013-04-03T16:02:50.000+0200},
  author = {Feldman, Ronen},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2e60a4ce1b7f5d1ac7ed734664fcb5844/flint63},
  doi = {10.1145/2436256.2436274},
  file = {ACM Digital Library:2013/Feldman13cacm.pdf:PDF},
  groups = {public},
  interhash = {5d9d370ba329bf9a2723c31e3a322060},
  intrahash = {e60a4ce1b7f5d1ac7ed734664fcb5844},
  issn = {0001-0782},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  keywords = {v1205 acm paper ai language processing information retrieval emotion analysis},
  month = {apr},
  number = 4,
  pages = {82-89},
  timestamp = {2013-04-03T16:02:50.000+0200},
  title = {Techniques and Applications for Sentiment Analysis},
  username = {flint63},
  volume = 56,
  year = 2013
}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Delete all auto-generated files as a first step. If you're familiar with other build chains, this is equivalent to cleaning your project.  The `.aux` file is the usual suspect.

Comment: provide the documentclass for a test. With the standard article class there will be no problem with your bibliography. However, the URL field in your first bib entry doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where might the file `mgr_eng.cls` be found? Does it load a bibliography style file automatically? If so, which one? If not, which bibliographystyle do you employ? Incidentally, the author field of the third entry is definitely incorrect. It should be `author = {Jurafsky, D. and Manning, C.},` rather than `author = {Jurafsky D., Manning C.},`. Observe that in an `author` field the word `and` is a keyword that serves to separate authors.

Comment: Thanks for your all answers. I had '#' in .bib file but I removed them after first occurence of error. But it didn't help because I compiled pdf viewer first.
Solution is simple - I had to compile in correct order - bibliography first and then pdf viewer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by (essentially) a typo.